# Does Yum have an equivalent to apt / aptitude's DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, yum, aptitude

On Ubuntu you can use something like this:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get update
```

Which will prevent things that require input (choosing grub versions or conflicts between configuration files, or even prompting for a `mysql` root password during install)

I checked the `man` page for `yum` but didn't see anything related to non-interactive usage other than `check-update` which "Returns exit value of 100 if there are packages available for an update"

Does Yum have an equivalent to apt / aptitude's `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` ?

Comment: `yum/rpm` doesn't have an equivalent to `debconf`. It doesn't do things like prompt for a `mysql` password.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By long-standing convention, RPMs themselves *never* ask for any interactive input. Batch mode is assumed. Some terrible vendor RPMs may attempt anyway, but since they're not supposed to do that, there's never been much call to have an external feature to work around the bad behavior — just avoid or fix those RPMs.

Sometimes yum itself asks for confirmation. For this, you can give `-y` to tell yum to assume "yes".

Answer (score 6):

`yum` has the `-y` option.  Adding this tells `yum` to assume "yes" as the answer to any question asked.